# ActiveRecord way of sorting a group before ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this active record query:

```
@reviews = Review.limit(30).group('user_id').order('created_at desc')
```

I'm using the group method to ensure I only display one review per user. 
The problem is that this review is not necessarily the last created review by that user.

I understand grouping happens before ordering so is it possible somehow to sort a group before calling order?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem. Even if I put `order` before `group`, the `group` always happens before the `order`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ids = Review.group(:user_id).maximum(:created_at).keys
@reviews = Review.limit(30).where(:id => ids).order(:created_at)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I still end up with the earliest review for each user. I suspect this is due to the maximum(:created_at) call. If I wanted to list in decending order then I would have 'created_at desc' but it looks like maximum doesn't like the desc parameter

Comment: have you tryied `@reviews = Review.limit(30).where(:id => ids).order('created_at DESC')`?

Comment: Yep, tried that too. All ids returned by the first statement are those of the first review for that user.

Answer (score 0):

I have found many answers to this question but each requires raw sql, when you have simple query you can use it, for your input it will be something like this:

```
Review.find_by_sql(
 "SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT * FROM reviews
 ORDER BY reviews.created_at DESC ) as my_table
 group by my_table.user_id
 LIMIT 30"
)
```

but if query is more complicated and need more joins then you can use the almost good solution mentioned earlier, I am not sure if it is the best solution but it works for me:

```
ids = Review.order('created_at DESC').pluck(:id)
@reviews = Review.where(id: ids).group(:user_id).limit(30)
```

**edit:** Yes, the last solution isn't right because it executes two queries to DB. I have accidently came back to this problem today and I have used the `to_sql` method (shipped with > Rails 3.0) along with first solution, for me its perfect - 1. still one query, 2. subquery can be as complicated as you wish and the code readability will remain same:

```
Review.find_by_sql(
     "SELECT * FROM (
     #{ Review.order(:created_at).to_sql }
     ) as my_table
     group by my_table.user_id
     LIMIT 30"
    )
```